# Does every evaluation map $g: \Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/(\ker \pi) \to \Bbb{Z}$ factor some evaluation map $f:\Bbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]$ be the polynomial ring.  I know that every evaluation ring hom $f: \Bbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \Bbb{Z}$ is determined by where you send $X$ and $Y$.  Let $I = (X^2 - Y^3)$ for example, but it could be generated by any collection of polynomials.

Let $\pi : \Bbb{Z}[X, Y] \to \Bbb{Z}/I$ be the canonical map.  I know that if $\ker f \supset \ker \pi$, then we can make a well-defined map $g : \Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/I \to \Bbb{Z}$ simply by setting $g(\pi(x)) := f(x)$.  So in a sense there is an evaluation map from $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/I$ onto $\Bbb{Z}$.

My question is the converse, given a surjective "evaluation map" $g : \Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/I \to \Bbb{Z}$ does there exist some evalution map $f:\Bbb{Z}[X,Y] \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f = g \circ \pi$?

Firstly, I'm not sure if evaluation map from the quotient is even a well-formed concept.

Comment: yes. let $a=g(X+I)$ and let $b=g(Y+I)$. then, by the universal property of commutative polynomial algebras, there is a unique ring morphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]\to\mathbb{Z}$ taking $X$ to $a$ and $Y$ to $b$. but $g\circ\pi$ has the same action on $X$ and $Y$, and so by uniqueness we will have $f=g\circ \pi$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, Thanks!  Do there exist evaluation maps of the quotient ring that are non-surjective?

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped! :) answer: not if your ring morphisms are unital (ie satisfy $g(1+I)=1$.) indeed, if $g$ is unital then we must have $$n=\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}=\underbrace{g(1+I)+\dots+g(1+I)}_{n\text{ times}}=g(\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}+I)$$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom.  One more question.  What if $I = (X^3 -Y^4 )$ but $g(X^3 - Y^4) \neq 0$ ??  Then how can the $\ker f \supset \ker \pi = I$?  Which I thought was strictly required for $f$ to factor through the quotient.

Comment: well, note that, since $X^3-Y^4\in I$, we have $X^3-Y^4+I=0+I$ in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}\big/I$; ie $X^3-Y^3+I$ is the additive identity in $\mathbb{Z}\big/I$. but ring morphisms must preserve the additive identity, so – since $g:\mathbb{Z}\big/I\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring morphism – we must have $g(0+I)=0$, ie $g(X^3-Y^4+I)=0$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, Thanks for your guidance.  Suppose $g(X + I) = 3, g(Y + I) = 2$, then $f(X^3 - Y^4) = 27 - 16 \neq 0$ so that $I \not\subset \ker f$.  How is that possible, since I thought that $f$ factors through $\pi$ if and only if $\ker f \supset \ker \pi$.

Comment: ah, but in this case, $g$ is not a well-defined map, as your argument shows! :) indeed, if $g$ were a well-defined ring morphism, we would have $$0=g(0+I)=g(X^3-Y^4+I)=g(X+I)^3-g(Y+I)^4=3^3-2^4=11,$$ a contradiction. so the problem here is that there *does not exist* a ring homomorphim $g:\mathbb{Z}\big/I\to\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $g(X+I)=3$ and $g(Y+I)=2$ :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom In conclusion we can safely say that the integer solutions to $X^3 - Y^4 = 0$ is in one-to-one correspondence with evaluation homomorphims from $\Bbb{Z}[X,Y]/(X^3 - Y^4)$ onto $\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom why haven't people applied this concept to solving multivariate, polynomial diophantine equations perhaps, or have they?

Comment: to some extent, I imagine that the field of [arithmetic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_geometry) originates with those kinds of connections; although you would be better off asking someone more knowledgeable about the field! :)